# Generating function for set of binary strings of equal block length

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Where blocks would be consecutive 0's or consecutive 1's. So 0000 would be a block of length 4.

I'm not even sure how such a set would look? Would the following elements at least be in the set (so I have a better idea):

0, 1, 01, 10, 000, 111, 0000, 1111, 0011, 1100

Comment: This is rather unclear.  Can you say more precisely which binary strings you are talking about?

Comment: The set of binary strings which have equal block length is all the problem says. The book the problem comes from defines blocks of binary strings to be as I defined above (000 is a block of length 3, 11111 is a block of length 5, 010101 is not a block although it contains blocks of length 1)

Comment: But you haven't defined the "block length" of a string.  I think perhaps what you mean is "the set of binary strings whose blocks are all of equal length"?

Comment: If you find the generating function $f(x)$ for binary strings with blocks of length $1$, think about what $f(x^k)$ might mean.

Answer (score 2):

For every divisor $d$ of $n$, there are exactly two strings with length $n$ and block length $d$: one starts with $0$'s and the other starts with $1$'s.  So if $f(n)$ is the number of binary strings composed of equal block lengths, then $f(n)=2d(n)$ where $d(n)$ counts the number of divisors of $n$.

The *ordinary* generating function of $f$ is $2\sum_n d(n)x^n$, and you can't say much more than that, though Geoffrey Critzer points out the Lambert series expansion
$$\sum_{n\ge1} d(n)x^n = \sum_{n\ge1}\sum_{d|n}x^n=\sum_{d\ge1}\sum_{k\ge1}x^{kd}=\sum_{d\ge1}\frac{x^d}{1-x^d}.
$$
  However, the Dirichlet generating function is more interesting:
$$\sum_{n>0} \frac{f(n)}{n^s} = 2\sum_{n>0}\frac{d(n)}{n^s}=2\zeta^2(s)$$
where $\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann zeta function.  (See [this link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletGeneratingFunction.html).)

Comment: I think you left out a factor of 2 on the far right hand side.

Comment: For what its worth, the ordinary generating function is 2*Sum_{k>0} x^k/(1-x^k).

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer Indeed; duly noted.